# Rails Routing -- Adding Custom Route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I'm almost certain that someone has asked this question before, but I can't seem to hit on the right series of words to find it.

I have a resource, Games, with all of the normal resource-y paths. Create, Edit, etc.

I've created a new action within GamesController called json that I want to be able to access at mydomain.com/games/json but the routing keeps picking up 'json' as the ID and routing it to the 'show' action instead.

Presumably this is because of the default route:

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))'
```

I've tried a number of things, but no matter what I do it keeps routing to 'show.' I've been attempting to figure it out using [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#customizing-resourceful-routes), but for someone that's pretty new to rails its quite a bit to take in and apply.

I'd like to say that for any controller /json would take you to the json action (instead of show with id 'json'), but I'd settle for having to specify it for every controller individually.

Any help is greatly appreciated. (Even if that's just pointing me to the already answered question.) In all cases I've been placing the route I'm attempting to create above the default route.

My routes:

```
  root :to => 'home#index'
  resources :events, :players, :sets, :matches, :characters, :videos, :games, :event_instances, :game_instances
  resource :user_session
  resource :account, :controller => "users"
  resources :users
  match '/login', :to => 'user_sessions#new', :as => 'login'
  match '/logout', :to => 'user_sessions#destroy', :as => 'logout'
  match '/register', :to => 'users#create', :as => 'register'
  match '/games/json', :to => 'games#json', :as => 'gameList'
  match ':controller(/:action(/:id))'
```

Comment: Can you please show your routes ? We need it to answer efficiently.

Comment: Probably should have known. They've been added.

Comment: Thanks, I've answered you're question below I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
resources :games do
  collection do
    get :json
  end
end
```

if you also wanted to add an action that would take an `:id` path segment and return, say, json representation of a specific game, you'd do that with

```
resources :games do
  collection do
    get :json
  end
  member do
    get :json
  end
end
```

I'd add that when I was brand new to Rails (less than 1.5 years ago), the routing dsl was really hard for me to get my head around for some reason. But it's worth studying that guide, despite the fact that it's a bit overwhelming at first. Otherwise you'll end up with a bunch of `match '/route/to/somewhere' => 'controller#action', :as => :some_helper`, which ends up being a pain to read & maintain and will make it harder to have a consistent "grammar" for your urls.

Edit: looking at your now-posted routes file, the problem is that you declare the `games/json` route after the `resources :games` declaration. Route-matching precedence proceeds from the top of the file down, so the resourceful route for `games` matches first, and the specific route declared later is never checked. If you use the syntax above to make your `json` route a part of the resource declaration, this won't happen.

Comment: Spot on.
It's kind of hard to look for answers when you're not sure what you're looking for. 
Thanks a ton. (That section in the guide I linked makes a lot more sense now that it has some context around it.)

Comment: cf. NicoArbogast's answer. His strategy would define a `json` route for *all* your resource controllers, which might be behavior you'd want to have. (I'd still use `get` rather than `match`, personally.)

Answer (score 2):

Ok so what you need to do is put your custom json route above your other resources routes and make it default like so:

```
get '/:controller/json(/:id)', action: 'json'
resources :events, :players, :sets, :matches, :characters, :videos, :games,         :event_instances, :game_instances
...
```

Your confusion was linked to the way the routes are built and urls are parsed

Think of your routes.rb file as a set of consecutive filters to be applied to the url requested by the client.

If you put a default route above another it will catch all request that match the given pattern => this means that when you were adding all your resources routes above your json route, all urls matching the /#{resources}/:id pattern (and /games/json is one of them) were caught before they could reach the json custom route.

By putting your custom route above the others, you make it catch any request matching the pattern, that means in that case all requests with

```
/#{controller_name or resource_name)}/json(/:id)
```

---

NB:

I am not quite sure this is the best design pattern to use for your routes and I'd rather go with conventional REST routes with basic CRUD actions that would implement the respond_to pattern to answer specific json requests.

See docs for this: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to

Adding such 'catch all' routes on top of all your resources may become risky when your app grows.

But you may have your reasons to go this way, in that case, I think my answer matches what you need.